# AWS on Terraform: Error deleting resource: timeout while waiting for state to become 'destroyed'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform (`v0.12.28`) to launch my AWS environment (`aws provider v2.70.0`).
When I try to remove all resources with `terraform destroy` I'm facing the error below:

```
error deleting subnet (subnet-XXX): timeout while waiting for state to become 'destroyed' (last state: 'pending', timeout: 20m0s)
```

I can add my Terraform code but I think there is nothing special in my resources stack which basically includes:

1. VPC and Subnets.
2. Internet and NAT GTWs.
3. Application Load Balancers.
4. Route tables.
5. Auto-generated NACL and Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs).

In my case, the problem seems to be related to the ENIs which are attached to the ALBs - as can be seen from the AWS console:

[image]

While searching for solutions I noticed that it is a common problem which can come in different resources and type of dependencies.

**I'll focus in this question to problems which are related to VPC components** (Subnets, ENIs etc') and **resources that have dependency on them** (Load Balancers, EC2,Lambda functions etc') **and are failing to be deleted** probably due to the fact that a detaching phase is required prior to the deletion.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

---

(*) The Terraform user for this environment (DEV) has full Admin privileges:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So this shouldn't be related to policies.

---

Examples for related issues:

[Update: Issue affecting HashiCorp Terraform resource deletions after the VPC Improvements to AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/update-issue-affecting-hashicorp-terraform-resource-deletions-after-the-vpc-improvements-to-aws-lambda/) (Solution doesn't work - I've an updated version of AWS provider).

[AWS VPC - cannot detach "in use" AWS Lambda VPC ENI](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/e75hq7/aws_vpc_cannot_detach_in_use_aws_lambda_vpc_eni/)

[Lambda Associated EC2 Subnet and Security Group Deletion Issues and Improvements](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10329)

[AWS: deletion of subnet times out because of scaling group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terraform-tool/GOIfZu9lNXw)

[Error waiting for route table (rtb-xxxxxx) to become destroyed: timeout while waiting for state to become](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/243)

[Error waiting for internet gateway to detach / Cluster has node groups attached](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/10934/555646312)

Comment: did you add any component manually after deployed the VPC ?

Comment: OK, a small correction, I've added via kubectl  K8S resources and an AWS ALB ingress which I guess might caused the problem..

Comment: And found the relevant problem over here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/issues/536 specific for my case.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue while trying to destroy an EKS cluster after I had already deployed services onto the cluster, specifically a load balancer. To fix this I manually deleted the load balancer and the security group associated to the load balancer.

Terraform is not aware of the resources provisioned by k8s and will not clean up dependent resources.

If you're unsure what resources are preventing Terraform from destroying infrastructure you can try an of:

- Use `terraform apply` to get back into a good state and then use `kubectl` to clean up resources before running `terraform destroy` again.
- This knowledge base article includes a script you can run to identify dependencies: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-dependency-error-delete-vpc/
- Review CloudTrail logs to see what resources were created. If this was an issue with EKS you can filter by username: `AmazonEKS`.

Another variation of this issue is a `DependencyViolation` error. Ex:

> Error deleting VPC: DependencyViolation: The vpc 'vpc-xxxxx' has dependencies and cannot be deleted. status code: 400

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just now…

One (hacky) solution is to attempt to delete the subnet through the AWS Console. AWS will then tell you what is preventing the subnet from being deleted—for me, it was two network interfaces that needed to be detached and then deleted before Terraform had the power to delete my subnets.

Like [Mathew Tinsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250005/mathew-tinsley) says, there are sometimes associated resources created implicitly by AWS that Terraform can't destroy by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while destroying step function, and the problem was that it had active executions (status: Running). I stopped them and it successfully deleted the step function.